# Open React Component into Personal Tab

Tags: reactjs, authentication, tabs, microsoft-teams, openurl

I created a custom team app, this app is split into 2 parts, one is a personal tab and the other is a messaging extension.
How can I open a React component of my app from a messaging extension Adaptive Card action?
I tried Action.OpenUrl but I have to pass some data from the messaging to the personal card and inside it retrieve the authentication token with the received data and it works but is not strongly authenticated by the browser.
With the link everyone can open and view the item and that's not what I have to do.
I thought about using Action.Submit and passing some data (token or data to get it) into it,
but I don't know how to retrieve the data passed from sending the messages and then pass them to the personal card with http post (if possible) or how to pass the token to the tab.
I think this flow is safer. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can add authentication to message extension. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/add-authentication) and [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/add-authentication)?

Comment: I've already add it, but my question is: how can I use Action.OpenUrl and open it only if user is authenticated? Now if I open the link from another pc it correctly open the detail because the link have inside some params used for  get the auth token inside the react component of the Tab. The Action.OpenUrl is a http get, I'm need to change it http post. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: where you are using the action,open url in sign in card? Could you please share more details.

Comment: You've right. I use the adaptive card when the messaging extension return results, for create preview 
and result card. Inside the result card I use one button for open url and this url send me to my personal tab where I get the authenticated user token and then get the item details. When the user make the search is already authenticated. My problem is how send param to my url without using the url querystring parameter.

Comment: I think the best choice would be to use a post call or a get call with header params but I have read that it can only be used for outlook.

Comment: You cannot send parameters with out using query parameters. this is by design.

Comment: I know this. I had ask if I can use some other microsoft teams action or or other function (as described in the other comments as http Post or others ) for do that. Thanks.

Comment: Currently we don't have any workAround. Could you please raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Teams does not support passing parameters without using query parameters.
Could you please raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform).